# How to layout the grid cells from Left to Right (Top to Bottom) with horizontal scroll using GridView.builder, in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, gridview

I have set up a GridView.builder to scroll horizontally with 2 rows.

However, I want the grid cells to be built out from Left to Right, Top to Bottom (e.g. the top row would build 1,2,3,4 then the remaining 5,6,7 on the second row.).

I tried a Wrap widget but that doesn't have a scroll function and can't seem to get this working.

[image: Example image]

```
final times = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
...
  SizedBox(
              height: size.height * 0.25,
              child: GridView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: times.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Center(child: Text(times.elementAt(index).toString())),
                ),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2, crossAxisSpacing: 6, mainAxisSpacing: 6),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `scrollDirection` to `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`, and update `crossAxisCount: 4`.

Updated code :

```
 SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              child: GridView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: 8,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: SizedBox(child: Center(child: Text("Hey $index"))),
                ),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 4, crossAxisSpacing: 6, mainAxisSpacing: 6),
              ),
            ),
```

Result will be -
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, in my example I would like to retain the horizontal scroll (ie scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal)

Comment: How would you go the other way.  Top-bottom then left-right?